# Symfony: Unknown "humanize_bytes" filter

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In a Symfony 2.7 app, we have attempted to set up a `humanize_bytes` Twig filter in order to convert long numbers of bytes into human-readable form -- `10 MB`, for example.

Within our `HumanReadableBytesExtension.php` file is the following:

```
public function getFilters() {
  return [
    new TwigFilter('humanize_bytes', [$this, 'getHumanReadableBytesFilter'])
  ];
}
```

... and in our `services.yml` file lies the following:

```
mycompany.cms.twig.extension.human_readable_bytes_extension:
  class: MyCompany\TwigExtensions\HumanReadableBytesExtension
    arguments:
      - '@translator'
    tags:
      - {name: twig.extension}
```

... but we find that the `getFilters()` method is not getting called, and that when we try to call the filter in a Twig template, we get:

> Unknown "humanize_bytes" filter.

Both files pass syntax validation. The cache has been cleared. Is there somewhere else where we should be registering this filter?

====

**Edit:** Here is the output of the `app/console debug:container mycompany.cms.twig.extension.human_readable_bytes_extension` command:

> [container] Information for service
>   mycompany.cms.twig.extension.human_readable_bytes_extension Service Id
>   mycompany.cms.twig.extension.human_readable_bytes_extension Class
>   MyCompany\TwigExtensions\HumanReadableBytesExtension Tags
>       - twig.extension                 () Scope            container Public           yes Synthetic        no Lazy             no
>   Synchronized     no Abstract         no

Comment: have you cleared cache?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have cleared the cache without improvement. I'll edit my question to mention that.

Comment: And what does `bin/console --env=prod debug:container mycompany.cms.twig.extension.human_readable_bytes_extension` say?

Comment: Does your class extends `\Twig_Extension`?

Comment: DanCostinel: The class extents an abstract class that in turn extends \Twig_Extension. 
@emix: Good call. The production-mode call gives me an error, but I have now placed the non-production version in the question.

Comment: Why don't u just implement the filter in an existing working extension btw?

Comment: Well I would attach the debugger to the Twig loader then and check why the extension is not getting registered.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are using an abstract class. Did you override the `getName` method in your `HumanReadableBytesExtension` ?

If two extensions have the same name, only one will be loaded, the second will be silently ignored.

Comment: We do indeed override the `getName()` method. A quick search through our codebase shows that there's no other extension claiming that name.

Comment: Too bad :) Really thought this is the problem, ran into it a couple of times. could you run `debug:twig extension_name` to make sure?

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately just took all of my changes and put them on a fresh feature branch. That "fixed" the problem, albeit in a very non-satisfactory way. (We never really did figure out what was going wrong.)